# How to do a conditional Cache::flush in Laravel file cache

Tags: php, laravel, caching

Suppose i have stored 5 different values (in real situation it is above 500) to laravel file cache.

```
Eg:
Cache::forever('key1','value1');
Cache::forever('key2','value2');
Cache::forever('key3','value3');
Cache::forever('key4','value4');
Cache::forever('key5','value5');
```

Suppose after sometime an event trigger occured, then i need to delete the values assosiated with

> "key2","key3","key5"

. But still i need the values in the

> "key1" & "key4"

keys.
If event trigger not occured, the all values are still have in the cache.

I know about the 'Cache Tags', but in the documentaion 'Cache Tags' are not available in 'file cache' and also available in 'memcached'.
My server RAM is only 512mb.

Any solutions?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here, but I'm guessing you want to delete some values even if the event you mention about doesn't trigger,  in which case, set an expire date for the item.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a particular key from the cache by simply calling

```
Cache::forget('key');
```